# Angular migration - Hybrid application is not bootstrapping

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, webpack-4

I am working on migrating my Angularjs 1.6 application to Angular 7 via ngUpgrade route, after all done when I'm trying to bootstrap my hybrid application, it's failing to bootstrap, I noticed that my main.ts file isn't executing at all where as I've added it as entry point in my webpack config.

I'm using template.ejs file as template in my HtmlWebpackPlugin. For Webpack settings and package.json, Please check my application bundling and bootstrapping code on github here:
https://github.com/mmmathur/AngularMigration

I tried with renaming it as index.ts as well but still no luck.

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { AppModule } from '../client/ngApp/ngApp.module';

const app = require('../client/app');
let appRoot = document.createElement('div');
const uiView = document.createElement('ui-view');
let body = document.querySelector('body');

appRoot.appendChild(uiView);
body.appendChild(appRoot);

console.log('executing main.ts');//even this statement is not executed
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then((platformRef) => {
  const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, [app]);
  console.log('hybrid application is bootstrapped');

})
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```

ngAppModule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {UpgradeModule} from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { AppComponent } from './ngApp.component';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    UpgradeModule

  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [

  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

ngApp.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'ng-app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Angular 7 application bootstraped</h2>
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Expected: my Hybrid application gets bootstrapped.

Actual: a blank screen with no error thrown.

**UPDATE** Issue was these lines:

```
optimization: 
  {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  }
```

Optimization was causing this issue, once I removed above config option from webpack, application at least starting bootstrapping, though this time I'm getting error like:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2547)
    at CompileMetadataResolver../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:17874)
    at CompileMetadataResolver../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:17767)
    at CompileMetadataResolver../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:17635)
    at CompileMetadataResolver../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (compiler.js:17445)
    at compiler.js:17559
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:17547)
    at CompileMetadataResolver../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (compiler.js:17445)
    at compiler.js:17532
```

I tried to fix this by adding polyfills.ts file in my project

Polyfills.ts

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'core-js/client/shim';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js';
```

but still getting same error, I'm using core-js 3.2.1.
looking if someone have idea about what's going wrong with my code?

**UPDATE** I learned that I supposed to add polyfills.ts file in HtmlWebpackPlugin-->chunks array as well, after adding, it started picking polyfills file and now that error has gone and now my angularjs app also getting bootstrapped along side angular 7 app, however now I'm getting another error like:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $$UpgradeModule due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {"default":"ui.app"} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object


https://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.10/$injector/modulerr?p0=%24%24UpgradeModule&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20%7B%22default%22%3A%22ec.customer.servicing.ui.app%22%7D%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20Argument%20'module'%20is%20not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object%0A%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.10%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3D%257B%2522default%2522%253A%2522ec.customer.servicing.ui.app%2522%257D%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255Bng%253Aareq%255D%2520Argument%2520'module'%2520is%2520not%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520Object%250Ahttps%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.6.10%252Fng%252Fareq%253Fp0%253Dmodule%2526p1%253Dnot%252520a%252520function%25252C%252520got%252520Object%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fng1.bundle.js%253F29bb21d813a74a626d53%253A32020%253A12%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520assertArg%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fng1.bundle.js%253F29bb21d813a74a626d53%253A33994%253A11)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520assertArgFn%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fng1.bundle.js%253F29bb21d813a74a626d53%253A34004%253A3)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fng1.bundle.js%253F29bb21d813a74a626d53%253A36915%253A11%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fng1.bundle.js%253F29bb21d813a74a626d53%253A32313%253A20)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fng1.bundle.js%253F29bb21d813a74a626d53%253A36889%253A5)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fng1.bundle.js%253F29bb21d813a74a626d53%253A36907%253A40%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fng1.bundle.js%253F29bb21d813a74a626d53%253A32313%253A20)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fng1.bundle.js%253F29bb21d813a74a626d53%253A36889%253A5)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520createInjector%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fng1.bundle.js%253F29bb21d813a74a626d53%253A36806%253A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fng1.bundle.js%3F29bb21d813a74a626d53%3A32020%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fng1.bundle.js%3F29bb21d813a74a626d53%3A36929%3A15%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fng1.bundle.js%3F29bb21d813a74a626d53%3A32313%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fng1.bundle.js%3F29bb21d813a74a626d53%3A36889%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fng1.bundle.js%3F29bb21d813a74a626d53%3A36907%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fng1.bundle.js%3F29bb21d813a74a626d53%3A32313%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fng1.bundle.js%3F29bb21d813a74a626d53%3A36889%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fng1.bundle.js%3F29bb21d813a74a626d53%3A36806%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fng1.bundle.js%3F29bb21d813a74a626d53%3A33860%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fng1.bundle.js%3F29bb21d813a74a626d53%3A33881%3A12)
    at angular.js:125
    at angular.js:5034
    at forEach (angular.js:418)
    at loadModules (angular.js:4994)
    at createInjector (angular.js:4911)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1965)
    at Object.bootstrap (angular.js:1986)
    at bootstrap (static.js:76)
    at static.js:1595
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
```

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're migrating from AngularJS probably the `<script>` tag for your bundle is inside the `head` segment. Move it to the **end** of `body`

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  ... ...

  <script src="dist/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```